# How to get specified probability from selectOutput5 block, particularly same for each group where each agents are from some specified group

Tags: anylogic

Let us assume every agent are from some group and there are total 10 group. There is a group id as parameter in each agent.

I include a SelectOut5 block in Anylogic model and specified 0.25, 0.40, 0.35, 0, 0 as probability in selectOutput5 block. let us assume I have total 1000 agents then I agree the aggregate output of selectOutput5  will be like 250, 400, 350, 0, 0. But i want this type of output for each group like for group1 if total agents are 100 then output should be like 25, 40, 35, 0,0. if 200 then output should be like 50, 80, 70, 0,0. similarly for each group

So please suggest the logic, how to use selectOutput5,  so that I will get expected result from selectOut5

Tried: Specified probability 0.25, 0.40, 0.35,0, 0 in selectOutput5 block

Expecting: specified probability for each group , not only aggregate

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that returns the probability for each of the 5 exits based on the agent's group. So the function input is the agent's group, the output is the expected probability. Create 5 functions.

In the SelectOutput, call each of the 5 functions for each exit and give it the arriving agent (i.e. for exit 3 you'd call `getProbExit4(agent)`)